# Microsoft.TeamFoundation Attempting to link AreaPath with Team

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm building an interface via C# to Azure Devops via the Microsoft.TeamFoundation libraries. We're importing this data into our warehouse so that we can integrate high level summary information from our Azure Devops boards into our VP's daily dashboard - things like story points per team, total backlog assigned, etc.

The issue is that I need to find the link between an assigned work item, like a Feature, UserStory, etc. and the Team associated with it. From my understanding, a Team is associated with a work item via their assigned Area Paths. I can use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.TeamHttpClient` to obtain the list of teams, I can use `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` to obtain the area paths, but what do I need to use to get the currently assigned links between the Team and their assigned AreaPaths?

Comment: Have you looked at capturing this data using PowerBI and/or OData instead of building your own tool?

Comment: Yes - neither will suit our use case for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the "[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Work.WebApi Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet)" in your C# program. Within this Namespace, you can get the default area path of a specific team via the "[TeamFieldValues Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi.teamfieldvalues?view=azure-devops-dotnet)" or "[WorkHttpClientBase.GetTeamFieldValuesAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi.workhttpclientbase.getteamfieldvaluesasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Work_WebApi_WorkHttpClientBase_GetTeamFieldValuesAsync_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_Core_WebApi_Types_TeamContext_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)".

This is corresponding to the REST API "[Teamfieldvalues - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamfieldvalues/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll give this a shot and let you know how it works!

Comment: @user15833466, any update, feel free to tell us.

Comment: thanks a ton for your help! One issue, though, is that while this does return a link between the team as defined by the TeamContext class and their default AreaPath, it doesn't allow me to link up all of the available area paths to their appropriate team - i.e. my team has four AreaPath assignments, however, this will only give me the default AreaPath. Is there any way to get all of the links?

Comment: Marked as solved -- TeamFieldValues.Values is an array of all applicable AreaPaths. Thanks!